# Default echo web framework body limit size

Tags: go, go-echo

I'm getting 413 status code on accessing some endpoint developed using echo [web framework](https://echo.labstack.com/docs).

Is there a way to know what's the default body limit size? I found a way to set this limit [here](https://echo.labstack.com/docs/middleware/body-limit), but there's no mention of the default limit.